# What is supposed to happen when an img can't be displayed?

Tags: html, image, cross-browser

What is the browser supposed to do exactly when an img can't be displayed?

The official sources are deliberately vague about this. They say the alt text is supposed to be used, but they don't say *how*!
So unless I haven't searched good enough (and I did a lot of Googling. I even Binged!) this information isn't there. And the browsers differ widely in what they do.

If an image can't be loaded because it isn't there,

- Mozilla displays the alt text inline as part of the current text
- IE displays the alt text as an inline-block, preceded by the "broken image" icon, and in a different font
- Chrome also displays an inline block and the "broken image" icon, and it puts a border around it. It doesn't change the font though.

```html
<p>This is my new car.
  <img src="images/mynewcar.jpg" alt="It's a red car, with four wheels."/>
  And that's it.</p>
```

Now if you change the browsers' settings to not load images, the behaviour changes in most browsers.

- Chrome now doesn't display anything, not even the alt text.
- IE still displays the alt text in a smaller font, but now without the "broken image" icon in front.
- Mozilla still displays the alt text inline.

So my question is, which of these browsers does the right thing?

And by that I don't mean, "what do you think is the best approach"? I really mean what are the official rules governing this behaviour? Are there W3C pages (or even WHATWG pages) that I managed to miss, or where I misinterpreted the rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that there are no hard and fast rules around this. The HTML spec only describes how a browser can be *expected* to behave, but imposes no normative requirements upon browsers to follow said behavior to the letter. The CSS spec doesn't even touch on it.

[Section 10.4.2 of W3C HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#images) describes how `img` elements are rendered according to a set of rules that refer to what the `img` elements *represent*.

[Section 4.7.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element), a ways down, describes what an `img` element represents depending on its `src` and `alt` attributes:

> What an `img` element represents depends on the `src` attribute and the `alt` attribute.
>
> *[...]*
>
> **If the `src` attribute is set and the `alt` attribute is set to a value that isn't empty**
>
> The image is a key part of the content; the `alt` attribute gives a textual equivalent or replacement for the image.
>
> If the image is available and the user agent is configured to display that image, then the element represents the element's image data.
>
> Otherwise, the element represents the text given by the `alt` attribute. User agents may provide the user with a notification that an image is present but has been omitted from the rendering.

So, if an image is unavailable, an `img` element represents its alt text (since there is no image to be represented!).

So, going back to section 10.4.2, the following rule applies:

> **If the element is an `img` element that represents some text and the user agent does not expect this to change**
> The user agent is expected to treat the element as a non-replaced phrasing element whose content is the text, optionally with an icon indicating that an image is missing, so that the user can request the image be displayed or investigate why it is not rendering. In non-graphical contexts, such an icon should be omitted.

It seems that Firefox is following this expectation (note: not *requirement*) most closely, though whether the box that is generated is replaced or non-replaced, I'm not sure. Likewise for the other browsers — an inline-block can either be replaced or non-replaced. Notice that HTML says "phrasing element", not "inline element" or "inline-block element", again adding to the vagueness of the whole thing.

What Chrome does when images are disabled through user preference is not what I would call "[providing] the user with a notification that an image is present but has been omitted from the rendering", but again, it's also not a requirement. Still, I don't understand why Chrome thinks that's a good idea. What was alt text for, again?

Answer (score 0):

From MDN  HTML  element `<img>`IMG

> Browsers do not always display the image referenced by the element.
> This is the case for non-graphical browsers (including those used by
> people with vision impairments), if the user chooses not to display
> images, or if the browser is unable to display the image because it is
> invalid or an unsupported type. In these cases, the browser may
> replace the image with the text defined in this element's alt
> attribute.

The default behavior si display the content of alt attribute

see [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)  ref  MDN doc for ref
You can also refer tho [this W3C ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H37.html)

And this http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/NOTE-UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20-20150226/understanding-techniques.html understanding techniques for for WCAG Success Criteria

Comment: Yes, so MDN too says the alt text can be used, but not how it's supposed to be displayed. Hm.

Comment: That paragraph seems to be referring to non-graphical browsers specifically.

Comment: Not only. The role of alt attribute on img is exactly this. When the image  is not displayer (tipical the non graphicals browser but also and  an error in img visualization)  the alt message help the user showing a textual description of the  image.

Comment: My bad, I misread. It says for non-graphical browsers, *or* if images are disabled, *or* if images are otherwise unavailable.

Comment: @BoltClock Right. And that's why I find it strange that Chromium does only display the alt text if images are NOT disabled! So there must be something I'm overlooking. Or, something the developers at Chromium are all overlooking.